# Dart, Can't call Generic's method

Tags: generics, dart, flutter, generic-programming

I am trying to create an abstract data model where i pass data and type a and then is return list, but when i can't call `T.fromJson()` method, note that passes type has method `fromJson()`

```
class DataList<T> {
  final bool success; 
  dynamic data;


  InfosResponse({
    this.success,
    List<dynamic> data,   
  }) {
    castDataToList(data);
  }

  factory DataList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataList(
      success: json['success'],
      data: json['data'],
    );
  }

  void castDataToList(jsonData) {
    this.data = List<T>.from(jsonData.map((x) => T.fromJson(x)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You cannot call static methods on type variables. Static methods must be known at compile-time, and the value of a type variable is not known until run-time.

You can parameterize your class with the method that you want to call:

```dart
class DataList<T> {
  final bool success; 
  dynamic data;
  T Function(Object) fromJson;

  DataList({
    this.success,
    List<dynamic> data,   
    this.fromJson;
  }) : data = castDataToList(data);

  factory DataList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json, T fromJson(Object o)) {
    return DataList(
        success: json['success'],
        data: json['data'],
        fromJson: fromJson,
    );
  }

  List<T> castDataToList(jsonData) =>
      [for (var x in jsonData) fromJson(x)];
}
```

When you want to use the class with a type, `Foo` which has a `fromJson` static method or constructor, you create the instance as:

```dart
var dataList = DataList<Foo>.fromJson(someJsonMap, Foo.fromJson);
```

This passes the `Foo.fromJson` function to the class, which can then use it when needed.

Comment: How can I use this class ?

Comment: T dynamic Function(Object) fromJson; What means of this line ? T dynamic ?

Comment: Constructors - `Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)` - don't seem to work, only static methods - `static Foo fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)`. Why?

Comment: Why isn't `Some<T extends SomeClass>` a static method?  If this `SomeClass` (or a subclass) has a static method of `fromJson()` we would know all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

to use Irn answer with constructors try passing them like this

```
(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Foo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
```